# Move a file to a new folder, keeping Git history

Tags: macos, git, command-line

I am looking to move a folder so that it resides in another folder.

Currently:  /folder1, moved to /holder/folder1, for example.

What is the easiest way to do this both on my home machine (Mac) and git to ensure that all of the history of the files within that folder remain on github.

Sorry for the newb question.  I have only a very basic working knowledge of git, and would like to keep this as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the source and destination directories both within the same existing git repository? It looks like they would be in your example; if they're not, it's a bit more complex of a question.

Comment: Jefromi, yes, they are both within the same repository.  I just want to consolidate a couple of directories under a new directory.  (Moving them a level further from root)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From git documentation,

```
git mv [-f] [-n] <source> <destination>
git mv [-f] [-n] [-k] <source> ... <destination directory>
```

In the first form, it renames , which must exist and be either a file, symlink or directory, to . In the second form, the last argument has to be an existing directory; the given sources will be moved into this directory.

The index is updated after successful completion, but the change must still be committed.

Comment: So, I would use git mv source... dest directory, where dest directory is an existing directory, then commit, and done?  Will this move the files on my local machine as well?  Thanks for your prompt response.